# In notmuch search results, which maildir contains each of the emails?

Tags: email, mutt, notmuch

I am using `notmuch` with the mua `mutt` (actually, `neomutt`). When I perform a search, all matching mail is accessible via a special maildir which I can open in `mutt`. However, I do not see any way to display the actual maildir in which each of these emails is stored?

Technically, I see that `notmuch` creates a temporary maildir which contains dynamic links pointing to the mail files in their different maildirs. So the information is accessible through the path of these dynamic links, but this is not very convenient.

It is also rather dangerous in terms of managing one's correspondence, as outgoing e-mails in the `postponed` mailbox are displayed just as e-mails that have actually been sent.

A mutt macro to switch to the maildir of the email would be good, e.g. 
Even better, a command to (re)move it from that directory if its current storage is erroneous.

Comment: Are you using mutt or neomutt ?

Comment: I'm using neomutt.

Comment: Since it seems it'll require programming, I've asked a similar-minded coding question at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042384/in-notmuch-search-results-how-to-find-which-maildir-contains-each-of-the-emails